# Immutables and Lagom with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lagom

I am running in to a problem trying to use Intellij to import the lagom-java seed code.  I create the project with activator new.  Then I follow instructions for setting up annotation processing here
https://immutables.github.io/apt.html#intellij-idea 
and the additional steps from here http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.1.x/java/ImmutablesInIDEs.html
After this, most everything is resolved except for the namedCall, pathCall etc methods.  Any idea what I could be missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try updating jdk to latest version and make sure that IntelliJ and project uses this JDK. It helped me for some strange compliation errors, releated to lambas and generics.

Comment: Thanks Bartosz  I will give that a try.  An update from jetbrains would be nice too.

Comment: Have you tried running Make project? I imported the lagom-cargotracker project in IntelliJ and everything resolves just fine.

Answer (score 2):

That's a bug in IntelliJ's Java 8 support, they still haven't got their type inference quite right. It happens for me too, and it's completely unrelated to immutables.

As Java gets more complex type inference, Java developers are going to have to get more tolerant of seeing red in their IDEs. Having used Scala for many years, I don't even notice red in my IDE any more.

Comment: Yes i figured, and I have gotten the same way with Scala.  I can live with it.  Thanks James.